# Не могу сделать импорт

Tags: java, импорт

У меня на данный момент вот такое дерево
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Суть в том, что я в классе `Main` и `MainWindowController` хочу сделать импорт класса `TableIncome`, но автоматически IDEA не хочет это делать (я про сочетание Alt+Enter), да и руками тоже не получается, всегда пишет - `Cannot resolve symbol 'TableIncome'`, раньше класс `Main` был в корне `src`. Я вычитал, что так импорт не делается, и надо классы из `src` оборачивать пакетом. Так я создал пакет `address` и засунул все туда. Этот вариант не помог. Можно сделать импорт не класса, а всего пакета `model`, но тогда методам класса `TableIncome` выдает `Cannot access address.model.TableIncome`. Помогите разобраться что к чему

Alt + Enter не работает
[image: Alt + Enter не работает]

Код класса `TableIncome`

```
package address.model;

import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

/**
 * Хранение данных для таблицы "Тип дохода"
 */

public class TableIncome {
    private StringProperty type;

    private IntegerProperty january;
    private IntegerProperty february;
    private IntegerProperty march;
    private IntegerProperty april;
    private IntegerProperty may;
    private IntegerProperty june;
    private IntegerProperty jule;
    private IntegerProperty august;
    private IntegerProperty september;
    private IntegerProperty october;
    private IntegerProperty november;
    private IntegerProperty december;

    public TableIncome(){
        this(null);
    }

    /**
     * Конструктор с начальными данными
     * @param type
     */
    public TableIncome(String type){
        this.type = new SimpleStringProperty (type);

        /**
         * начальные данные
         */
        this.january = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);
        this.february = new SimpleIntegerProperty (0);
        this.march = new SimpleIntegerProperty (0);
        this.april = new SimpleIntegerProperty (0);
        this.may = new SimpleIntegerProperty (0);
        this.june = new SimpleIntegerProperty (0);
        this.jule = new SimpleIntegerProperty (0);
        this.august = new SimpleIntegerProperty (0);
        this.september = new SimpleIntegerProperty (0);
        this.october = new SimpleIntegerProperty (0);
        this.november = new SimpleIntegerProperty (0);
        this.december = new SimpleIntegerProperty (0);
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type.get();
    }

    public StringProperty typeProperty() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type.set(type);
    }

    public int getJanuary() {
        return january.get();
    }

    public IntegerProperty januaryProperty() {
        return january;
    }

    public void setJanuary(int january) {
        this.january.set(january);
    }

    public int getFebruary() {
        return february.get();
    }

    public IntegerProperty februaryProperty() {
        return february;
    }

    public void setFebruary(int february) {
        this.february.set(february);
    }

    public int getMarch() {
        return march.get();
    }

    public IntegerProperty marchProperty() {
        return march;
    }

    public void setMarch(int march) {
        this.march.set(march);
    }

    public int getApril() {
        return april.get();
    }

    public IntegerProperty aprilProperty() {
        return april;
    }

    public void setApril(int april) {
        this.april.set(april);
    }

    public int getMay() {
        return may.get();
    }

    public IntegerProperty mayProperty() {
        return may;
    }

    public void setMay(int may) {
        this.may.set(may);
    }

    public int getJune() {
        return june.get();
    }

    public IntegerProperty juneProperty() {
        return june;
    }

    public void setJune(int june) {
        this.june.set(june);
    }

    public int getJule() {
        return jule.get();
    }

    public IntegerProperty juleProperty() {
        return jule;
    }

    public void setJule(int jule) {
        this.jule.set(jule);
    }

    public int getAugust() {
        return august.get();
    }

    public IntegerProperty augustProperty() {
        return august;
    }

    public void setAugust(int august) {
        this.august.set(august);
    }

    public int getSeptember() {
        return september.get();
    }

    public IntegerProperty septemberProperty() {
        return september;
    }

    public void setSeptember(int september) {
        this.september.set(september);
    }

    public int getOctober() {
        return october.get();
    }

    public IntegerProperty octoberProperty() {
        return october;
    }

    public void setOctober(int october) {
        this.october.set(october);
    }

    public int getNovember() {
        return november.get();
    }

    public IntegerProperty novemberProperty() {
        return november;
    }

    public void setNovember(int november) {
        this.november.set(november);
    }

    public int getDecember() {
        return december.get();
    }

    public IntegerProperty decemberProperty() {
        return december;
    }

    public void setDecember(int december) {
        this.december.set(december);
    }
}
```

Comment: Странно. `import adress.model.TableIncome` должно работать. В любом случае, если вы использовали что то из TI, или создавали объект TI, и он подчеркивается красным, поставьте на него курсор и нажмите Alt+Enter(вроде как, короче которое показывает возможные действия при ошибке), и там должен быть пункт с импортом.

Comment: @AntonSorokin к сожалению Alt + Enter не работает

Comment: @Serodv наверное все таки метод

Comment: @AntonSorokin на скриншоте просто конструктор, `public static void main(String[] args)` присутствует ниже, причина я думаю не в этом, да и в контроллер я тоже не могу сделать импорт

Comment: А у вас `public` класс? Что происходит при зведочном импорте? `import......*;`

Comment: класс `public`, как и писал, если сделать импорт всего пакета, на методах висит ошибка, с текстом - `Cannot access address.model.TableIncome`

Comment: Покажите код класса TableIncome

Comment: @Алексей я добавил код в вопрос

Comment: Проверь, не назван ли у тебя класс Tablelncome через L а не через I (И)

Comment: @Алексей Класс назван TabLeincome (сменил регистр для понимания), а разве имя класса влияет на авто импорт? согласен с тем, что может возникнуть такая ошибка когда прописываешь руками импорт, но импорт пакета наверное решила бы эту проблему

Comment: @AntonSorokin я не знаю в чем причина, но помогло переключение jdk на 8ую версию